# SQL vs NoSQL for data that will be presented to a user after multiple filters have been added

Tags: sql, object, attributes, nosql, filtering

I am about to embark on a project for work that is very outside my normal scope of duties. As a SQL DBA, my initial inclination was to approach the project using a SQL database but the more I learn about NoSQL, the more I believe that it might be the better option. I was hoping that I could use this question to describe the project at a high level to get some feedback on the pros and cons of using each option.

The project is relatively straightforward. I have a set of objects that have various attributes. Some of these attributes are common to all objects whereas some are common only to a subset of the objects. What I am tasked with building is a service where the user chooses a series of filters that are based on the attributes of an object and then is returned a list of objects that matches all^ of the filters. When the user selects a filter, he or she may be filtering on a common or subset attribute but that is abstracted on the front end.

*^ There is a chance, depending on user feedback, that the list of objects may match only some of the filters and the quality of the match will be displayed to the user through a score that indicates how many of the criteria were matched.*

After watching this talk by Martin Folwler (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qI_g07C_Q5I), it would seem that a document-style NoSQL database should suit my needs but given that I have no experience with this approach, it is also possible that I am missing something obvious.

Some additional information - The database will initially have about 5,000 objects with each object containing 10 to 50 attributes but the number of objects will definitely grow over time and the number of attributes could grow depending on user feedback. In addition, I am hoping to have the ability to make rapid changes to the product as I get user feedback so flexibility is very important.

Any feedback would be very much appreciated and I would be happy to provide more information if I have left anything critical out of my discussion. Thanks.

Comment: 5000 objects seems excessive in any schema...is that 5000 tables?  Are you planning a table per customer or something?  Unless you are able to find/hire a dedicated NoSQL resource for you, learning as you go seems painful here...I'd recommend sticking to what you are comfortable and familiar with for an implementation of this scale.

Comment: Maybe I misused terminology here. By 5000 objects, I meant what would be considered 5000 rows in a SQL database.

Comment: @Twelfth Does my clarification make sense?

Comment: Yes it does, though I'm not sure on the SQL vs NOSQL answer for you.  5000 rows is pretty small for a database and I'd question why you'd go the NoSQL route here.  I would think a header table with a name value pair child table would be the setup best able to handle dynamic attributes (makes adding new ones simple as well).  Can describe that better for you if you want,you will have to familiarize yourself with SQL syntax on pivoting out the data though

Comment: @Twelfth I would greatly appreciate it if you could describe that a bit better. It appears to be what I'm looking for.

With regards to why NoSQL for such a small database, I'd say my answer is twofold. First, I like the ability to dynamically add attributes and have multiple similar attributes for a single object e.g., Phone1, Phone2, Phone 3. Second, if all goes well, the size of the database has the potential to grow rather quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May as well make this an answer.  I should comment that I'm not strong in NoSQL, so I tend to lean towards SQL.

I'd do this as a three table set.  You will see it referred to as entity value pair logic on the web...it's a way of handling multiple dynamic attributes for items.  Lets say you have a bunch of products and each one has a few attributes.

```
Prd 1 - a,b,c
Prd 2 - a,d,e,f
Prd 3 - a,b,d,g
Prd 4 - a,c,d,e,f
```

So here are 4 products and 6 attributes...same theory will work for hundreds of products and thousands of attributes.  Standard way of holding this in one table requires the product info along with 6 columns to store the data (in this setup at least one third of them are null).  New attribute added means altering the table to add another column to it and coming up with a script to populate existing or just leaving it null for all existing.  Not the most fun, can be a head ache.

The alternative to this is a name value pair setup.  You want a 'header' table to hold the common values amoungst your products (like name, or price...things that all rpoducts always have).  In our example above, you will notice that attribute 'a' is being used on each record...this does mean attribute a can be a part of the header table as well.  We'll call the key column here 'header_id'.

Second table is a reference table that is simply going to store the attributes that can be assigned to each product and assign an ID to it.  We'll call the table attribute with atrr_id for a key.  Rather straight forwards, each attribute above will be one row.

Quick example:

```
attr_id, attribute_name, notes
1,b, the length of time the product takes to install
2,c, spare part required
etc...
```

It's just a list of all of your attributes and what that attribute means.  In the future, you will be adding a row to this table to open up a new attribute for each header.

Final table is a mapping table that actually holds the info.  You will have your product id, the attribute id, and then the value.  Normally called the detail table:

```
prd1, b, 5 mins
prd1, c, needs spare jack
prd2, d, 'misc text'
prd3, b, 15 mins
```

See how the data is stored as product key, value label, value?  Any future product added can have any combination of any attributes stored in this table.  Adding new attributes is adding a new line to the attribute table and then populating the details table as needed.

I beleive there is a wiki for it too...  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model

After this, it's simply figuring out the best methodology to pivot out your data (I'd recommend Postgres as an opensource db option here)

Comment: Any comment from the -1 vote?  I thought it was a good explaination on why an entity - attribute model would be best for this given the want for quickly adding new attributes.  As a side note...as long as you are not on MySQL (or MS Access) this model scales well, I've had mutli-billion row tables in a postgres environment handling this very well.

Comment: EAV is an anti-pattern if you want any level of scalability. For simple data models, it may be able to fly, but at some level of complexity it falls apart. Indexing is all but impossible, and queries can reach a level of complexity where performance tuning requires rocket scientist knowledge of querying and database internals. The more complex your data model and the number of entities you're tracking, the worse of an idea EAV becomes.

Comment: Well thank you, I think I just got called rocket scientist.  His example is 5000 rows with 10 to 50 attributes...a 486 with MSAccess could probably handle it and I don't see the level of complexity here that would run into issues.  I'm not saying you are wrong that the EAV model eventually hits scaling issues, but that limit is far beyond what he has here.  Would you recommend not using oracle in this case because of it's 128 terabyte tables space limit too?

Comment: No, but your comparison between the limitations of EAV and Oracle is spurious. EAV is a known scalability anti-pattern. It's well documented as such and, when I find it in the wild, is universally one of the top performance problems on the server.

Comment: I'm not comparing the limitations of EAV and Oracle, I'm comparing how far away from those limitations this scenario is. We are talking a volume well below 1% of hitting scalability problems...if you prefer the comparisson, would you dispute me using my truck to move a 5 lbs box on the basis that it can only 'scale up' to carrying 5 tons?

Answer (score 3):

This problem can be solved in by using two separate pieces of technology. The first is to use a relatively well designed database schema with a modern RDBMS. By modeling the application using the usual principles of normalization, you'll get really good response out of storage for individual CRUD statements.

Searching this schema, as you've surmised, is going to be a nightmare at scale. Don't do it. Instead look into using [Solr/Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/solr) as your full text search engine. Solr's support for dynamic fields means you can add new properties to your documents/objects on the fly and immediately have the ability to search inside your data if you have designed your Solr schema correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there a reason you would avoid going the NoSQL route as described in the other answer?

Comment: Because the relational model holds up well, the level of scale you're talking about can be easily handled by both commercial and open source RDBMSes, and you can avoid the pain of search with something like Solr. While I do love me some NoSQL (I even write a database client for fun), there is potentially overhead involved beyond the initial ease of "just throwing stuff in a document". Scaling may not be as simple as you think and you will find it easier to find experts with an RDBMS than with a NoSQL solution.

Comment: Oh, and the EAV model just doesn't scale in an RDBMS. It'll do fine until you run out of free memory and then it will bottom out rapidly. You can scale with money for a while, but eventually you'll hit a limit.

Comment: @zgall1 - echo of Jeremiah : "you will find it easier to find experts with an RDBMS than with a NoSQL solution"   NoSQL is still young and the expertise in it is still being developed...it makes finding support and resourcing a bit more challenging.  Availability of a NoSQL resource should be considered in your descision here

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert in NoSQL, so I will not be advocating it. However, I have few points that can help you address your questions regarding the *relational* database structure.

First thing that I see right away is, you are talking about *inheritance* (at least conceptually). Your objects inherit from each-other, thus you have additional attributes for derived objects. Say you are adding a new type of object, first thing you need to do (conceptually) is to find a base/super (parent) object type for it, that has subset of the attributes and you are adding on top of them (extending base object type).

Once you get used to thinking like said above, next thing is about inheritance mapping patterns for relational databases. I'll *steal* terms from Martin Fowler to describe it here.

You can hold inheritance chain in the database by following one of the 3 ways:

1 - **Single table inheritance**: Whole inheritance chain is in one table. So, all new types of objects go into the same table.

Advantages: your search query has only one table to search, and it must be faster than a join for example.

Disadvantages: table grows faster than with option 2 for example; you have to add a `type` column that says what type of object is the row; some rows have empty columns because they belong to other types of objects.

2 - **Concrete table inheritance**: Separate table for each new type of object.

Advantages: if search affects only one type, you search only one table at a time; each table grows slower than in option 1 for example.

Disadvantages: you need to use union of queries if searching several types at the same time.

3 - **Class table inheritance**: One table for the base type object with its attributes only, additional tables with additional attributes for each child object type. So, child tables refer to the base table with PK/FK relations.

Advantages: all types are present in one table so easy to search all together using common attributes.

Disadvantages: base table grows fast because it contains part of child tables too; you need to use join to search all types of objects with all attributes.

### Which one to choose?

It's a trade-off obviously. If you expect to have many types of objects added, I would go with Concrete table inheritance that gives reasonable query and scaling options. Class table inheritance seems to be not very friendly with fast queries and scalability. Single table inheritance seems to work with small number of types better.

Your call, my friend!