# Optimal database structure

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I am developing an production control application for a local distillery, and I am having issues structuring the database.

A core feature is the users ability to create spirit types, these types all have an associated production process. Each process can have multiple steps. There are 7 different types of steps.

When the user creates a "batch" of some spirit, a spirit type will be chosen and the user will be presented with a "wizard" following the production process defined. At each step, the user will input information related to that step.

What I came up with was this many-to-many relationship:

```
spirits (spirit types)
- id
- name

steps (steps in the production process)
- spirit_id
- state_id

states (names of all possible steps)
- id
- name
```

While this worked for the creation of the spirit types, it lacked when it came to filling in the data. Since each step in the production process step takes different data:

```
distillation
- abv
- mass

dilution
- abv
- water

filtration
- density
- volume
```

What would be an optimal structure for an application of this sort?

Comment: I love SQL, but what you're describing really sounds like it's a problem for Mongo or some other nosql database. I've used Mongo with some success, and it works well in my experience. I work in Java, and I've found plenty of high-quality resources for working with Mongo in that language. I assume the situation is similar for most major languages. (This isn't a plug, and I prefer using SQL for most things.)

Comment: I use key/value pair for these setups.  It's not the most scaleable, but unless you have a few million processes, it should work.   Name value pair, key value pair, attribute value pair, EAV....all references to the same thing.  Many dev's won't opt for this.  another scenario : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19458613/sql-vs-nosql-for-data-that-will-be-presented-to-a-user-after-multiple-filters-ha

Answer (score 1):

for me you should use a few some table for manage a master/detail relation between process and stess .. a relate this to similare class of steps

```
activity (class of steps in the production process)
 - activity_id 
 - name

process_phase  (master table for process steps)
 - process_phase_id
 - description 
 - activity_id
 - spirit_id

process_phase_detail  (detail table for process step )
 - process_phase_id
 - detail_id
 - state_id
```

PS  -- data modelling (without severe specification) is an opinion based area ..